# Javascript, jQuery play pause button with href html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to make a href to pause play the HTML 5 video with javascript but i has not yet succeded this is my html:

```
<a href="" class="play-pause">play-pause</a> 

<video poster="bg.jpg" loop id="bg-vid"></video>
```

and this is my javascript (I have no to very little experience with javascript so this was my guess on how it would look but it did not work)

```
$(".play-pause").click, '#bg-vid'(function(e){
    var video = $(this).get(0);
    if (video.paused === false) {
        video.pause();
    } else {
        video.play();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: The a tag is empty, so there's nothing to click on.  Also, nothing has class `but`, so I don't know why you're using that as your selector...

Comment: Sry, my bad. removed the text for some reason, now the class is correct and text added in the a

Comment: `$(".play-pause").click, '#bg-vid'(function(e){` isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to have a single pause button that controls multiple videos, you should probably change play-pause from a class to an id:

```
<a href="" id="play-pause">play-pause</a>
```

Also, I'd declare the click handler inside the a tag as well, rather than assigning it at runtime:

```
<a href="" id="play-pause" onclick="playpause()">play-pause</a>
```

Then, in the js, define a function called `playpause()` that calls `$('#bg-vid').pause()` or `$('#bg-vid').play()` as appropriate.